# Possible to have multiple keys for a value in a Map? If not then how to do this?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to have multiple keys for a value in a Map in javaScript. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) on Mozilla doesn't seem to suggest it so I'm not sure. An example is that I'm getting input from the user in the form of a string, and I want to match that string to the matching object with the same name. alexander is the name of one of these objects. However, I also want "alex" or maybe "ali" to be acceptable inputs. In the current form below, only "alexander" will match the alexander object. If it is not possible to do this with maps, I'd like to know what's a good way I can match user string input with object names that doesn't involve using a bunch of if statements (there may be some names that have dozens of nicknames).

```
var john = {
  age: 20
  wt: 185
  favFood: pizza
};

// alexander, wesley etc. all have the same fields, just different values

// Map (used to validate user input)
const personByKey = new Map([
  ["john", john],
  ["alexander", alexander] // I also want "alex" to be acceptable for alexander obj
  ["wesley", wesley]
]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you want

```
const personByKey = new Map([
  ["john", john],
  ["alexander", alexander],
  ["alex", alexander],
  ["wesley", wesley]
]);
```

Comment: Oh, simple enough that I would never have thought of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need a master lookup dictionary with all of the possible nicknames that map to the key to use in the personByKey map.

```
let nicknameMap = {
  "alex": "alexander",
  "al": "alexander",
  "alexander": "alexander",
  "john": "john",
  "j-dog": "john"
   "al": "alexander",
}

var person = personByKey[nicknameMap["al"]];
```